# How do I check users email isn't already in my database when submitting a form?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express, mariadb

This is my first question here, so apologies for any errors.
I'm building a test, where users can sign in, and retake the test. However, I'm not sure how to check if the email is already in my mariaDB when a user submits form.

I've seen some similar examples, using nested query, not sure if that would work here or if it's good practice.

```
/*User info POST*/
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.post('/user-info', (req, res) => {

    var first_name = req.body.first_name;
    var last_name = req.body.last_name;
    var email = req.body.email;

    var sql = `INSERT INTO Govt_profiles 
        (
            First_Name, Last_Name, Email
        ) 
        VALUES 
        (
            ?,?,?
        )`;
    pool.query(sql, [first_name, last_name, email], (err, data) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log("User submition success!");
    });
    res.redirect('/questions');
});
```

I tried Tim's suggestion(Thank you!). However I'm now getting errors, I'm sure I'm forgetting something. This is my error:

UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Parameter at position 4 is not set
sql: INSERT INTO Govt_profiles (First_Name, Last_Name, Email)
                SELECT ?, ?, ?
                WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Govt_profiles WHERE Email = ?)

This is my updated code:

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.post('/user-info', (req, res) => {

    var first_name = req.body.first_name;
    var last_name = req.body.last_name;
    var email = req.body.email;

    var sql = `INSERT INTO Govt_profiles (First_Name, Last_Name, Email) 
        SELECT ?, ?, ? 
        WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Govt_profiles WHERE Email = ?)`;

    pool.query(sql, [first_name, last_name, email], (err, data) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log("User submition success!");
    });
    res.redirect('/questions');
});
```

Comment: make the email id column as primary key then catch the error

Comment: Instead you can make the email id column as unique so it will throw error so that you can capture.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option would be to use an `INSERT INTO ... SELECT` which checks for the existence of the email before actually inserting:

```
INSERT INTO Govt_profiles  (First_Name, Last_Name, Email)
SELECT ?, ?, ?
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Govt_profiles WHERE Email = ?);
```

You could then check the affected row count, and if zero, then you would know something went wrong.

If you can change the database structure, you could also try adding a unique index on the `Email` column:

```
ALTER TABLE Govt_profiles ADD CONSTRAINT email_unique UNIQUE (Email);
```

With this approach, attempting to insert a record with an email which already exists should result in an error in your Node.js code.

**Update** to your recent edit:

You need to bind the email *twice*, since it appears twice in two `?` placeholders:

```
var sql = `INSERT INTO Govt_profiles (First_Name, Last_Name, Email) 
    SELECT ?, ?, ? 
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Govt_profiles WHERE Email = ?)`;

pool.query(sql, [first_name, last_name, email, email], (err, data) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log("User submition success!");
});
```

Comment: Just bind the email twice, since there are two `?` placeholders for the email.

Comment: Thank you so much Tim! Thanks to everyone who pitched in too!

Answer (score 0):

The email column should have a unique constraint in database and while inserting you catch the wrapped exception in your service and act accordingly.

Comment: Hi Rakib, the select to check if the email exists would have to happen within the same serializable transaction, otherwise it might still be possible to insert overlapping identical emails.

Comment: Yes got that. That's why I think the data layer constraint is absolutely necessary.

Comment: If the `email` column is large, use a hash (eg, `MD5(email)`) kept in a `UNIQUE` column for checking for dups.

Answer (score 0):

```js
try {
 const rows = await conn.query("SELECT Email from Govt_profiles WHERE Email = $`req.body.email` ");
 if(count(email) < 0 ){
 const res = await conn.query("INSERT INTO Govt_profiles (First_Name, Last_Name, Email) value (?, ?, ")", [1, "mariadb"]);
 console.log(res); 
    }
  } catch (err) {
 throw err;
  }
```

Comment: on rows there should be `count(email)`