# Why is my MariaDB query not working on host but works locally?

Tags: node.js, mariadb, namecheap

This is my code that works fine locally, but not on Namecheap host:

```
//data connection pool
const pool = require('../models/database');
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');

module.exports = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const {user_name, password, email} = req.body;
        const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(password, 10);
        console.log(hashedPassword);

        let sql = `INSERT INTO userdb (user_name, password, email)
        SELECT ?, ?, ? 
        WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM userdb WHERE email = ? OR user_name = ?);
        SHOW WARNINGS;`;

        let result = await pool.query(sql, [user_name, hashedPassword, email, email, user_name]);
        
        console.log(result);
        console.log("the id: ", result[0].insertId);
        res.status(200).send("Success Comrad!");

        } catch (error) {
        res.status(400).send(error.message);
    }
    
}//module.export end
```

These are my dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
    "bcrypt": "^5.0.1",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.0",
    "express": "^4.17.2",
    "mariadb": "^2.5.5",
    "pug": "^3.0.2"
  }
```

This is the error I'm getting:

```
(conn=1698954, no: 1064, SQLState: 42000) You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM userdb WHERE email = 'dookie@gmail.com' OR us...' at line 3 sql: INSERT INTO userdb (user_name, password, email) SELECT ?, ?, ? WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM userdb WHERE email = ? OR user_name = ?); SHOW WARNINGS; - parameters:['dookie','$2b$10$OQp5lovlqmMfKNQtuvBK9e7t4rX39nVW22XdhzDZqBnSgDKv6G0ky','d...]
```

I also do have this set: `multipleStatements: true`
Any ideas why this may be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by approaching it differently. My main goal is to prevent duplicate entries.

I first set a unique constraint in PHPMyAdmin by doing this:

```
ALTER TABLE userdb 
ADD CONSTRAINT UC_email UNIQUE (email)
```

and then simplified my query:

```
let sql = `INSERT INTO userdb (user_name, password, email)
        VALUES (?,?,?)`;
```

Comment: You can use `INSERT IGNORE INTO userdb (user_name, password, email) VALUES (?,?,?);` to ignore errors if you try to insert twice the same email, or `INSERT INTO  userdb (user_name, password, email) VALUES (?,?,?) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE user_name = VALUES(user_name), password = VALUES(password);` if you prefer to update others columns

Comment: Yep, thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure this works locally ? Maybe to forgot some part of it

Your `SELECT` needs a `FROM` to work.

```sql
SELECT ?, ?, ? 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (/* removed */);
```

---

To answer to your second question, `multipleStatements: true` allow you to pass multiple queries at once. Here you ask to insert some data **and** to show possible warnings on it.

Comment: Hi thanks for your assist. Yea it works locally. I did have this query for the multipleStatements thing. ```    SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()`;``` But I deleted it for now. Do I not need it anymore for the Warning thing? Maybe I'm doing my query incorrect. What is the correct way to enter these 3 items into the database where no email or user_name is exact as what's being queried?

Comment: This other user helped me with that query: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57139401/how-do-i-check-users-email-isnt-already-in-my-database-when-submitting-a-form